# Configuring MemoryCache to run in a separate memory than application pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, memorycache

I am thinking of using `MemoryCache` in my application:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

How when I tested this, it functions more of less like old `Cache` in Asp.Net 2.0. It expires when application pool resets.

Is there any way I could prevent there so `MemoryCache` doesn't reset when application pool recycles? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried AppFabric ?